# Intuit App Center Try/Buy. Using HelloIntuitAnywhere .net sample app. Obtaining the realmID, access token, access secret

Tags: asp.net, oauth, intuit-partner-platform

From the Intuit App Center, on the Try/Buy.  The user enters Login information, then Authorizes the connection from my app to his QuickBooks company.  The user is taken to my wbesite.

The documentations says to run DirectConnectToInuit. So I have my landing page Redirect to directConnectToIntuit.aspx.  It works, except that it asks a second time  for Authorization to access the QuickBooks data.

I can get the SSO information from OpenIdHandler.aspx without re-entering sign-in info.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific issue, you should implement SSO, so that when a user comes from appcenter to the app, they are not prompted for credentials. You should be able to use the Open id identifier that is sent in the response from IPP along with the first name, last name, email id, realm to log the user in and then call Connect to QB.